# running old meteor app on new version

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have implemented some time ago small app in meteor framework. It was in time when meteor was in alpha stage.

Now trying to run that app on my local with new meteor and have following issue.

W20150103-00:59:21.595(1)? (STDERR)
W20150103-00:59:21.665(1)? (STDERR) /home/priv/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.38.ieqxkv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
W20150103-00:59:21.666(1)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20150103-00:59:21.666(1)? (STDERR)                               ^
W20150103-00:59:21.666(1)? (STDERR) TypeError: Object # has no method 'methods'
W20150103-00:59:21.666(1)? (STDERR)     at Accounts.urls (packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js:422:1)
W20150103-00:59:21.666(1)? (STDERR)     at /home/priv/Apps/musicapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/accounts-base.js:1614:4
W20150103-00:59:21.667(1)? (STDERR)     at /home/priv/Apps/musicapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/accounts-base.js:1657:3
W20150103-00:59:21.667(1)? (STDERR)     at /home/priv/Apps/musicapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:175:10
W20150103-00:59:21.667(1)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20150103-00:59:21.667(1)? (STDERR)     at Function.*.each.*.forEach (/home/priv/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.38.ieqxkv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20150103-00:59:21.667(1)? (STDERR)     at /home/priv/Apps/musicapp/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:86:5
=> Exited with code: 8
W20150103-00:59:23.876(1)? (STDERR)

The problem seems to be in accounts-base package but not sure how to solve that.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Prolly there is no more Accounts.urls method

Comment: Yes but it seems that this bug is in account package. Does it mean that this package is incompatible with new meteor?

Comment: It is compatible, did you run meteor update before meteor run? Also almost every package added using mrt add is deprecated, try to find them on atmospherejs, and add them using meteor add

Comment: I am using following packages accounts-base, accounts-ui, accounts-password. All are up to date. What do you mean adding by atmosphere instead of mrt?